# qooxdoo mobile selectbox from json

Tags: mobile, drop-down-menu, qooxdoo

I am trying to initialize / update a selectbox in Qooxdoo Mobile from json.

```
    this.__model = new qx.data.Array();
    var selQuestion = "substance released";
    sel = new qx.ui.mobile.form.SelectBox();
    sel.setDialogTitle(selQuestion);
    sel.setModel(this.__model);
    form.add(sel, selQuestion)
```

I have tried updating it using this method, but according to the manual the mobile lists are not supported yet.

```
test = ["item1", "item2"];
new qx.data.controller.List(new qx.data.Array(test), sel);
```

Also using the apply method on the property change I couldn't get it to work (the box stays empty):

```
__applySubstances : function(value, old) {
    this._model = new qx.data.Array();
    if(value) {
      for(i in value.toArray()) {
        this._model.push(value.toArray()[i].getName());
      }
    }
  }
```

Can anyone push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I see no faults in your code.
Could you please provide a playground example?

Please check the value parameter  of your __applySubstances method.

Here is the example from the mobile showcase:

```
 var dd = new qx.data.Array(["Web search", "From a friend", "Offline ad"]);
      var selQuestion = "How did you hear about us ?";
      this.__sel = new qx.ui.mobile.form.SelectBox();
      this.__sel.set({required: true});
      this.__sel.set({placeholder:"Unknown"});
      this.__sel.setClearButtonLabel("Clear");
      this.__sel.setNullable(true);
      this.__sel.setDialogTitle(selQuestion);
      this.__sel.setModel(dd);
      this.__sel.setSelection(null);

      form.add(this.__sel, selQuestion);
```

Comment: Thanks, I found the error. "this.__model = new qx.data.Array();" before the selectbox definition cleared the array after it was filled. Also I was loading the substances in the application.js. I guess the property change event calls the apply function from the causes the scope of the apply function to be something else than this page. Thus the this._model was not the one used by the selectBox at all.